# DynamicReports remove row if column is null

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I am a little bit stuck with such an easy problem. I am using DynamicReports and I want to hide whole row if column value is null. As I know, DynamicReports is based on JasperReports and it's possible there to do that by checking TextField's option "**Remove line when blank**". How can I do that in Dynamic?

Components, which I use:

```
TextColumnBuilder, ColumnGroupBuilder, JasperReportBuilder
```

I want to hide whole row if any of my TextColumns would be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after some thoughts, I found that this problem could be resolved in other way.

We gonna use column, group etc property `setPrintWhenExpression(DRIExpression expression)`

**1.**  Create class, which will handle, print or not to print the row. Dynamic has the abstract class for doing this:

```
    public class ShowExpressionDynamicReports extends AbstractSimpleExpression<Boolean> {

    private String fieldName;

    public ShowExpressionDynamicReports(String fieldName) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean evaluate(net.sf.dynamicreports.report.definition.ReportParameters reportParameters) {
        return reportParameters.getValue(fieldName) != null;
      }
    }
```

You should extend AbstractSimpleExpression in order to pass it as parameter to methods which are listed below.

So, the column value is printed if `evaluate(ReportParameters rp)` **returns true**.

I've also added field `fieldName` which allows me to print (or not) column due to **other's** column state.

**2.** Add property to your

**column:**

`setPrintWhenExpression(DRIExpression expression)`

**group:**

`.setPrintSubtotalsWhenExpression(DRIExpression expression)`

or

`setFooterPrintWhenExpression(DRIExpression expression)`

or

`setHeaderPrintWhenExpression(DRIExpression expression)`

Depends on what you want to hide.

**Example:**

We have 2 columns in our report: Product and ProductCount columns. I would like to hide Product column if ProductCount is null (we have no information for this Product).

So, to do that i will add property `PrintWhenExpression` to Product column

```
TextColumnBuilder<String> productColumn = col.column("Product", "Product", type.stringType())
.setPrintWhenExpression(new ShowExpressionDynamicReports("ProductCount"));
```